# VBA List all files (fast way) in subfolders without FileSystemObject

Tags: vba, subdirectory, dir

I'm searching for a way for fast listing all files from subfolders of folder. Approach based on FileSystemObject is too slow - it takes ~6 minutes for listing 416 filenames from a network drive (intranet), as I understand Dir() function doesn't allow for looping throught subfolders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use CMD instead:

```
Sub SO()

Const parentFolder As String = "C:\Users\bloggsj\folder\" '// change as required, keep trailing slash

Dim results As String

results = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & parentFolder & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll

Debug.Print results

'// uncomment to dump results into column A of spreadsheet instead:
'// Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Split(results, vbCrLf)), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(results, vbCrLf))
'//-----------------------------------------------------------------
'// uncomment to filter certain files from results.
'// Const filterType As String = "*.exe"
'// Dim filterResults As String
'// 
'// filterResults = Join(Filter(Split(results, vbCrLf), filterType), vbCrLf)
'//
'// Debug.Print filterResults
End Sub
```

Comment: It's just replicating opening cmd.exe and running a DIR command - it's a lot faster than FSO in my opinion though.

Comment: Is it possible to modify above call to search only for specific files extensions at once like :   .exe and .com ?

Comment: Yes, change `"*.*""` to `"*.exe""` or `"*.com""` for example. Alternatively, you could filter the result instead. I will edit the post to show how.

Comment: If I change "*.*" into "*.xls" it finds also ".xlsm" files, so it realize contain not equal call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81960/discussion-between-s-o-and-qbik).