# VBA listing all Files in subfolder using CMD, and sorting with manually input data

Tags: vba, excel

This question is based on a previous post from 2015: [VBA List all files (fast way) in subfolders without FileSystemObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132775/vba-list-all-files-fast-way-in-subfolders-without-filesystemobject)

The code below was initally provided by MacroMan, and it works great. However whenever I try to just get the file name, not full path, it doesn't seem to work. What adjustments need to be made to just retrieve the name of the file.(ie. if the retrieved path is C:/desktop/file.pdf I only want to retrieve "file")

Additionally, if the list in excel is constantly getting refreshed, and a corresponding column has user input, how can i get the user input to move with updated information from running the macro, so it doesn't get assigned to a file that isn't related. (ie. if "file1" is in A1 and a date "11/2" is manually input into B1, and then new files are placed into the subfolder, causing "file1" to move down a few rows to A7, how can i make sure the manually assigned date "11/2" automatically moves down to B7 to coincide with "file1"?)

```
Sub SO()

Const parentFolder As String = "C:\Users\bloggsj\folder\" '// change as required, keep trailing slash

Dim results As String

results = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & parentFolder & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll

Debug.Print results

'// uncomment to dump results into column A of spreadsheet instead:
'// Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Split(results, vbCrLf)), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(results, vbCrLf))
'//-----------------------------------------------------------------
'// uncomment to filter certain files from results.
'// Const filterType As String = "*.exe"
'// Dim filterResults As String
'// 
'// filterResults = Join(Filter(Split(results, vbCrLf), filterType), vbCrLf)
'//
'// Debug.Print filterResults
End Sub
```

I have attempted to use FSO with this script, but have also been unsuccessful:

```
Sub ListFiles()

    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objTopFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim strTopFolderName As String
    Dim path As String

    path = Range("I3").Value
    strTopFolderName = "C:\" & path & "\"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strTopFolderName)

    Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder, True)


End Sub

Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, _
    IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim NextRow As Long

    NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Cells(NextRow, "J8").Value = objFile.Name
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
        Next objFile

    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)
        Next objSubFolder

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the aversion to using `FileSystemObject`? You're obviously not on OSX or the `WScript.Shell` would fail.

Comment: I have used FSO already, but can't get it to work without duplicating file names. Meaning, if the macro is run more than once, it starts dumping file names that are already listed, below the previously listed file names from the first time the macro was executed

Comment: That sounds like an entire separate issue.  If you don't know how to use a screwdriver, hitting it harder with a hammer isn't the solution.  Check out [the examples in Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/990/scripting-filesystemobject), and if you're still having issues, look into using a `Scripting.Dictionary` (now included with the same reference!) for duplicate management.

Comment: The FSO I was running initially was good at providing what I needed, but given that it is listing all of the hidden files in the subfolders as well (which I don't need), it really bogs down the sheet in addition to reiterating file names. I have already been using Scripting.FileSystemObject. See edited post for previously used scripting.

Comment: To get the file name is a simple matter of text manipulation of the full path name.  To avoid duplicates you can use a Collection or Dictionary object.  Plenty of documentation of both.

Comment: @Comintern with regard to `FSO`, when I was doing some testing reading a folder and subfolders from a NAS box on my local network, using `wshshell.exec *(or run)* (CMD /C DIR ...)` resulted in the folders being read in about 1/5th the time with an absolute difference in minutes.  I doubt it applies here, given his path.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the path presented above isn't the actual path I will be using, as I am unable to provide that exact information per company policy. The folders and files will be quite extensive and I am currently using an FSO to find the files, but they still compound on one another in a column, and then I have to remove all duplicates and sort the non-duplicated column. However, it takes a stupidly long time to read the files and sort the data, thus my interest in using CMD if anybody has any info to help me out.

Comment: It looks like you already have the `CMD` method.

Comment: I do, yes, but I still am unable to get it to just list the file name as a result, not the entire path ( I figured "" /S /B /A:-D") would output just the file name, but it doesn't). And I still haven't been able to figure out if there is a method to sort manually-input data in a column adjacent to the listed file names, based on where the file names end up once running the code

Comment: Reread my previous comment

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm currently self-teaching myself all of this, please elaborate, I don't follow.

Comment: @jlinton The `wshshell.exec ...` method (or the `FSO` method) will both return the full path of the file.  You then must use text manipulation techniques to remove everything except the file name.  In VBA, one method would be to use the `Split` method to first return the last segment after the last '\', and then use it again to remove the file extension (`Split` using the `.` as the delimiter).  Then write that result to the worksheet.  Use a `Collection` or `Dictionary` to remove duplicates.  Search SO, MSDN and the internet and you will find thousands of examples as to how to use these.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks. I appreciate the description. I'll look into that and see how everything works out

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick pretty well.

```
Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, Subfolders As Boolean)

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\" and Flag as Yes or No

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File
'Dim r As Long
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured

    r = 14
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13
        Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
        Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type
        Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified
        Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"

        r = r + 1   ' next row number
    Next FileItem

    '--- This is the Function to go each and Every Folder and get the Files. This is a Nested-Function Calling.

    If Subfolders = True Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Check out the sample file from the link below.

http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/#file-manager

Click the link named 'Download Now'.

Comment: that does work, yes, thank you. But I have the capability to list all files from subfolders, that isn't my issue here as described in the question above.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work for me.  You can parse the string for the full path, using the Mid function to find the position of the last "\" and the InStrRev function to find the last "\"character.  So, it will look something like this:  Cells(iRow, 4).Formula = Mid(FileItem.path, InStrRev(FileItem.path, "\") + 1, 99)