# Iterate though all files of a certain path in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, file, filesystems, directory

I am trying to iterate over a bunch of .xlsx files in a particular drive such that any file fits the following format:

```
H:\[*FOLDER NAME*]\SpecificFolder\Finalized Plans\2019 Prefix[*].xlsx
```

In other words inside folders on the H drive with subfolders `\SpecificFolder\Finalized Plans\` containing `.xlsx` files starting with the literal phrase `"2019 Prefix"`. For example

```
H:\Widget\SpecificFolder\Finalized Plans\2019 Prefix Howdyado Neighbor.xlsx
```

or

```
H:\Rofl672\SpecificFolder\Finalized Plans\2019 Prefix Bob.xlsx
```

Is this something I can somehow iterate over using `Dir()`? Some other way?

Is it something like `Dir("H:\*\SpecificFolder\Finalized Plans\2019 Prefix*.xlsx")`? (this is what I tried and it gave me the error "Bad file name or number" so it may not be the right syntax)

Comment: @BigBen There are multiple such folders that may contain `\SpecificFolder\Finalized Plans\` etc and there won't necessarily be any similarities at all between those folder names, could be anything.

Comment: Try using the `FileSystemObject`, specifically the FolderExists method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/folderexists-method. Alternatively, try getting all files, in all subfolders, e.g. recurse the directory. Then apply your logic of which files you want after you have the full list.

Comment: @RyanWildry I don't understand how this addresses this specific problem? I don't necessarily know the folder names ahead of time to check if they exist, I'm trying to iterate through all files that have that pattern.

Comment: See my other comment, get all the files, then apply your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very fast approach using WScript, which does support wildcards.

```
'Adapted from --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31132876/4839827
Public Sub GetAllFilesMatchingPattern(StartingFolder As String, FolderPattern As String)
    If Right$(StartingFolder, 1) <> "\" Then StartingFolder = StartingFolder & "\"
    Dim StandardOutput As String
    Dim ws             As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim Files          As Variant
    StandardOutput = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & StartingFolder & FolderPattern & """ /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll

    If Not StandardOutput = vbNullString Then
        Files = Split(StandardOutput, vbCrLf)
        ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Files), 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Files)
    End If
End Sub


Sub Example()
    GetAllFilesMatchingPattern "H:\", "*\SpecificFolder\Finalized Plans\2019 Prefix*.xlsx"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are MANY ways to do this.  I think this will give you what you want.

```
Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, Subfolders As Boolean)

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\" and Flag as Yes or No

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File
'Dim r As Long
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured

    r = 14
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13
        Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
        Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type
        Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified
        Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" &amp; FileItem.Path &amp; """,""" &amp; "Click Here to Open" &amp; """)"

        r = r + 1   ' next row number
    Next FileItem

    '--- This is the Function to go each and Every Folder and get the Files. This is a Nested-Function Calling.

    If Subfolders = True Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

See the link below for all details.

http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

Click the link titled 'Download Now' to download a samaple file.