# How to run a fileExists check with a partial filename wildcard?

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard, file-exists

I have my fileExists code set up as below, however a portion of the file name (`_0107_1999986` below) is random and changes daily. Any idea how to wildcard that portion of the code so that the fileExists function results in a "proceed" if the other criteria is met?

```
Dim c As Boolean

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

c = fs.fileExists("M:\Fake\FakeXfer\" + Format(Now,"YYYYMMDD") + "_0107_1999986" + Format(Now-1, "YYYYMMDD") + ".csv"

IF Not c Then
    MsgBox "Check Later"
Else
    MsgBox "Proceed"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean with random? Any rules how the portion _0107_1999986 is derived resp. composed at run time of your code?

Comment: See if this answer helps --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101760/4839827

Comment: The documentation of `fileExists` does not say it accepts wildcards, only full file/pathnames. So you cannot use this method to determine if a file with a variable part in its filename exists.

Comment: That's the issue, no rules that i could easily figure out on the "_0107_1999986" portion. As far as i can tell it is probably a proprietary tag that our vendor uses.

Comment: I expect you could use a combination of two regular expressions to say if the file name begins with `Now, YYYYMMDD` and ends with `Now-1,YYYYMMDD`, then do whatever you need to. Have you worked with regex before?

Answer (score 0):

The following could work:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim myPathAndFile, c

    myPathAndFile = "M:\Fake\FakeXfer\" + Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD") + "*" + Format(Now - 1, "YYYYMMDD") + ".csv"

    c = Dir(myPathAndFile)
    If (c = "") Then
        MsgBox "Check Later"
    Else
        MsgBox "Proceed"
    End If

End Sub
```

Possibly the wild card in the middle of the filename won't work. Then use it as the last part before the extension and iterate over the results to validate the last part of the name.

Comment: Have you tested this? The way the answer is worded makes it sound like you're just guessing.

Comment: This is what I intially thought however, when using "*" in place of random porition the result is ALWAYS "Check Later". Which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I tested Paul's code and it's working for me. If there is a file like 20190109xyz20190108.csv in the directoy  I get the message "Proceed". So, are you sure about the naming <date>*<date -1>.csv

Comment: @Storax Strange, still not working for me. I'm sure about the naming convention. If I hardcode the "xyz" in the code results in proceed. Once i change the "xyz" to "*" it results in "Check later".

Comment: Ok, then I do not know what 's wrong. As said the code is working fine for me.

Comment: @harnar you did change from FileExists to Dir, right?  This code _should_ work for you?

Comment: I was able to figure out a workaround, appreciate the help!