# Get list of files recursively based on a date range

Tags: excel, vba

**Requirement**
I want to get a list of all files from a given folder (and it's sub folders) based on creation date being within a given date range

**My Knowledge**
I know I can loop through each file in a folder using:

```
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
```

Or I can use `DIR` to do something similar but both these options mean that I will be looping through each file in every folder (and sub folders).

**My Resolution - So Far**
What I am planning to do is to run a `DOS` command (through `Sheel`) and get the names of all files (that meet my requirement) into a text file and then perform my tasks on these files

**Question**
Is there a way that I can just get the names of all files (recursively through the folders) rather then looping through all files in each folder?

Comment: View this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414106/get-list-of-excel-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

Comment: You can take a look at this https://superuser.com/questions/32771/list-all-files-in-all-subfolders but you still need to go through txt file for getting data

Comment: Also if you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827715/get-list-of-sub-directories-in-vba It seems like in [VBA] we cant get subfolders (and subfolders) unless we use loops(With `FSO` or `Dir`)

Comment: Hi @GMalc: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that's the very thing I'm trying to avoid (looping through all files). I was hoping for something that would give me a list of all files

Comment: You can use `dir /s /b "Parent%Folder%Path"` to get whole list in a text file or you can use Shell object's `stdout` functionality to get the output into array.

Comment: @TanmayGawankar: Thanks for that. That's the solution I'm going for at the moment :)

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij: thanks for that. That is what I plan to do but was wondering if there was a similar thing within VBA to achieve that rather than me get the output in a file and then reading the file

Comment: @Zac May I know the reason for avoiding loops? Is it because of speed? You can use Shell object (Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation) which is quite fast that FSO method.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij: that's exactly it, for speed. I have thousands of files in the main folder and its sub folders. `Shell` is the option I'm going with for the very reason you have mentioned. My query was is there anything within VBA that would do something similar.. I don't know of one but there are a lot more knowledgeable people out there than me.. just thought I'd scratch there brains :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is a way to do this by using `WMI` and executing queries on `CIM_DataFile`. The subroutine below would recursively query each subfolder and gather files based on the `CreationDate` property.

```
Sub WMIGetFile()
Dim strComputer As String
Dim strDateFrom As String
Dim strDateTo As String
Dim fso, f, subf, oWMI, colFiles, cf

strComputer = "."
strDateFrom = "20180101000000.000000+00" ' 01/01/2018
strDateTo = "20191231000000.000000+00"   ' 12/31/2019

Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.getFolder("C:\FolderName\")

For Each subf In f.SubFolders
    Debug.Print subf.Path
    Set colFiles = oWMI.ExecQuery( _
        "SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile" & _
        " WHERE Drive = 'C:' AND Path = '\\" & Replace(Right(subf.Path, Len(subf.Path) - 3), "\", "\\") & "\\'" & _
        " AND CreationDate >= '" & strDateFrom & "'" & _
        " AND CreationDate <= '" & strDateTo & "'")

        For Each cf In colFiles
            Debug.Print cf.Name
        Next cf

    Set colFiles = Nothing

Next subf

End Sub
```

`Path` is formatted with `\\` instead of `\` as a path delimiter starting from the drive specified in `Drive`, hence the `Replace(Right())` method.

Also worth noting that WMI dates are formatted as strings by `yyyymmddhhmmss.000000`.

**EDIT:**

My brain missed the part where you need to execute this on the main folder as well. In that case, I'd just define it as a function and pass the parameters like this

```
Sub WMIGetFile()
    Dim fso, f, subf, oWMI
    Dim strComputer As String

    strComputer = "."

    Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.getFolder("C:\FolderName\")

    QueryCIMDATAFILE oWMI, f

    For Each subf In f.SubFolders
        QueryCIMDATAFILE oWMI, subf
    Next subf

End Sub


Function QueryCIMDATAFILE(conn, path)
    Dim colFiles, cf

    Dim strDateFrom As String
    Dim strDateTo As String


    strDateFrom = "20180101000000.000000+00" ' 01/01/2018
    strDateTo = "20191231000000.000000+00"   ' 12/31/2019

    Set colFiles = conn.ExecQuery( _
        "SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile" & _
        " WHERE Drive = 'C:' AND Path = '\\" & Replace(Right(path.path, Len(path.path) - 3), "\", "\\") & "\\'" & _
        " AND CreationDate >= '" & strDateFrom & "'" & _
        " AND CreationDate <= '" & strDateTo & "'")

    For Each cf In colFiles
        Debug.Print cf.Name
    Next cf

    Set colFiles = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tate. I haven't used `WMI` in this context before. I will give both answers a try and select the one that performs better. Thanks for all your effort

Comment: Thanks Tate. This is much faster than looping through files

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

Using DIR is fast to get all the files you need up front, and it works recursively. I'm unsure if DIR can filter files based on create date, so I mixed that approach with FSO. I'm getting good performance. I'm able to return ~45,000 or so files in ~8 seconds.

A quick note on the FolderPattern parameter. This is really a Folder or File Pattern. So you can pass in part of the path that should exist for each file you want to match. You can also use wildcards, for example `*.*` will return all files, or `*.txt` would return all text files.

```
 'Adapted from --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31132876/4839827
Public Sub GetAllFilesMatchingPattern(StartingFolder As String, FolderPattern As String, StartingDate As Date, EndingDate As Date)
    If Right$(StartingFolder, 1) <> "\" Then StartingFolder = StartingFolder & "\"
    Dim StandardOutput      As String
    Dim ws                  As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim Files               As Variant
    Dim FileArr             As Variant
    Static fso              As Object
    Dim FileCreationDate    As Date
    Dim j                   As Long

    If fso Is Nothing Then Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    StandardOutput = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & StartingFolder & FolderPattern & """ /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll

    'Exit if there was no output
    If StandardOutput = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    'Get all files that match initial filter
    Files = Split(StandardOutput, vbCrLf)
    ReDim FileArr(LBound(Files) To UBound(Files))
    j = LBound(Files)

    'Only include those which still exist and are in date range
    For i = LBound(Files) To UBound(Files)
        FileCreationDate = #1/1/1900#
        If fso.FileExists(Files(i)) Then FileCreationDate = fso.GetFile(Files(i)).DateCreated

        If FileCreationDate >= StartingDate And FileCreationDate <= EndingDate And FileCreationDate <> #1/1/1900# Then
            FileArr(j) = Files(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve FileArr(j)
    'Dump Data
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Files), 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(FileArr)
End Sub

Sub Example()
    GetAllFilesMatchingPattern "E:\", "*.*", #1/1/2000#, #1/29/2019#
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. This is along the lines of what I was thinking off but seems better as you are not getting the file list in a file. I will try both answers and which ever yields better performance, I will select as an answer. Saying that, both answers seem perfectly viable solution so thanks for all your efforts