# Getting a list of filtered filenames from directory and sub-directories into an array

Tags: excel, vba

I google searched and found lots of results for what I am looking for.  Did a lot of reading and my head is now hurting.  So there are many questions on this topic on this site alone and I was following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132775/vba-list-all-files-fast-way-in-subfolders-without-filesystemobject) from 2015.  I modified it to try to get it to work with filtered results but that did not work.  It was also grabbing the entire filepath and filename not just the filename.  Since i am not all that knowledgeable in VBA it was a little over my head what some of the commands were.

So I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414106/get-list-of-excel-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)  Which I like the accepted answer for.  I can read it and easily get a general understanding of what is going on with it.  The problem is it only looks in the current directory.

**How should it be modified to look in the sub directories and pull out a list of .xls filenames?**

I think I have a method for filtering it to xls files but also wondering if there is a better way.

This is my current code based on the second question:

```
'******************************************************************************
'** LIST DIRECTORY FILES                                                     **
'******************************************************************************
Public Function ListDirectoryFiles(ByVal FileDirectory As String, includeSubs As Boolean) As String()

Dim vaArray()   As String
Dim lCounter    As Long
Dim oFile       As Object
Dim oFSO        As Object
Dim oFolder     As Object
Dim oFiles      As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(FileDirectory)
Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

If oFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)
lCounter = 1
For Each oFile In oFiles
    If Right(oFile.Name, 4) = ".xls" Then
        vaArray(lCounter) = oFile.Name
        lCounter = lCounter + 1
    End If
Next

If lCounter < UBound(vaArray) Then
    ReDim Preserve vaArray(1 To nCounter - 1)
End If

'How to make it look in sub directories
'IF includeSubs then
'     ListDirectoryFiles FileDirectory, true
'     need add the results to vaARRAY somehow so
'     vaARRAY has results from all recursive calls?
ListDirectoryFiles = vaArray

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
 'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
    '  e.g. "*.txt"
    'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
    Function GetMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                        Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection
    
        Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr
        Dim colFiles As New Collection
        Dim colSub As New Collection
    
        Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        
        colSub.Add startFolder
    
        Do While colSub.Count > 0
    
            Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
            colSub.Remove 1
    
            For Each f In fldr.Files
                'check filename pattern
                If UCase(f.Name) Like UCase(filePattern) Then colFiles.Add f
            Next f
    
            If subFolders Then
                For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                    colSub.Add subFldr.Path
                Next subFldr
            End If
    
        Loop
    
        Set GetMatches = colFiles
    
    End Function
```

Example usage:

```vb
Dim colFiles as Collection, f, wb As Workbook
Set colFiles = GetMatches("C:\something\", "*RENS_RES*.xlsx")
For Each f in colFiles
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
    'work with wb
    wb.Close False
Next f
```

Comment: is that first DIM line supposed to be objects?

Comment: You're free to edit that if you want - sometimes I'm a bit lazy and leave things as the default Variant

Comment: Still learning so just want to make sure my edits would be right.  I am still reading through the routine and trying to wrap my head about the `IF subfolders` section and trying to figure out why you dont get stuck and a continuous loop of adding the same subfolders.

Comment: Folders only ever get added once to the `colSub` collection - eahc one is processed to list the files into the `colFiles` collection.  Note if you just want a set of filenames then you can use `colFiles.Add f.Name` instead of `colFiles.Add f` (which adds the `File` object itself)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Sub sample()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String

    HostFolder = "D:\"

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        ' Operate on each file
    Next
End Sub
```

Its from:
[Loop Through All Subfolders Using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645347/loop-through-all-subfolders-using-vba)

Comment: I read that question too at one point then got distracted by other questions.