# VBA: Replace hyperlinks in Word files within every subfolder in a given directory

Tags: vba, ms-word

Recently, my organization changed the name of our One Drive causing hyperlinks in my documents linking to other files in the One Drive to become obsolete.

I am trying to create a VBA script that will ask the user for a directory, go through each word doc in the folder and subfolder (and subfolder's subfolder, etc...) and replace a section of all the hyperlinks. I am new to VBA so please, don't hesitate to point out anything.

So far, this is what I have but I can't get it to change what's in the file, let alone go through all the subfolders:

```
    Sub getDirectory()

    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String
    
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    'Get the directory from user
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
    
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.doc*")
        
    End If
    
    'convert directory into string
    With xFd
    
        .Filters.Clear
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        Path = .SelectedItems(1)
        
    End With

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(Path)

End Sub



Sub DoFolder(Folder)

'loop through folders after calling LoopThroughFiles
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim File
    
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    
        DoFolder SubFolder
        
    Next
    
    For Each File In Folder.Files
    
        ' Operate on each file
        Call LoopThroughFiles
        
    Next

End Sub



Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim h As Hyperlink
    Dim sOld As String
    Dim sNew As String
    
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Documents.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
                
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                    
                    'Replace this:
                    sOld = "AAAA"
                    'With this:
                    sNew = "BBBB"
                    'Example: C:\Users\Me\AAAA\file.doc ---> C:\Users\Me\BBBB\file.doc
                    
                    'replace hyperlinks
                    For Each h In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
                        h.Address = Replace(h.Address, sOld, sNew)
                    Next h
                    
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                
            End With
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You're not saving your documents.  Plenty of questions here which cover searching a folder and all subfolders for files of a certain type: eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884001/478884

Comment: For code to loop through all Word documents in a folder and its sub-folders, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/168325-post2.html. All you need do is apply your hyperlink updating code instead of the font replacement code.

Comment: Thanks, that macro worked out for me!