Excel VBA Macro Works on Mac but Not on PC
Question: I have an Excel VBA macro that works perfectly on my Mac, but when I try to run it on a PC, it doesn't work as expected. The macro is intended to merge data from multiple Excel files into a single workbook, however, when I try run the Macro on my PC all it does is open a new file with the word "Ready" on the first cell(A1).
Here's a summary of what the macro does:

Initializes variables and settings.

Retrieves a list of files based on specified criteria using the GetFilesOnMacWithOrWithoutSubfolders function.

Processes each file in the obtained list, opening it, checking for specific data in the third worksheet, and copying it into a new workbook.

Cleans up and restores initial settings.


The issue arises when running the macro on a PC. It seems that certain parts of the code, such as AppleScript commands (MacScript), file paths handling, and possibly Excel version checks, are not compatible with Windows.
Here are my questions:

How can I modify the macro to make it compatible with both Mac and PC platforms?

Are there any Windows-specific commands or considerations I should be aware of when rewriting the code?

How can I handle differences in Excel versions between Mac and PC environments to ensure compatibility?


Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Code Snippet:
Option Explicit

'Important: this Dim line must be at the top of your module
Public MyFiles As String

Function GetFilesOnMacWithOrWithoutSubfolders(Level As Long, ExtChoice As Long, _
                                              FileFilterOption As Long, FileNameFilterStr As String)
'Ron de Bruin,Version 4.0: 27 Sept 2015
'http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac.htm
'Thanks to DJ Bazzie Wazzie and Nigel Garvey(posters on MacScripter)
    Dim ScriptToRun As String
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim FileNameFilter As String
    Dim Extensions As String

    On Error Resume Next
    folderPath = MacScript("choose folder as string")
    If folderPath = "" Then Exit Function
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ExtChoice
    Case 0: Extensions = "(xls|xlsx|xlsm|xlsb)"  'xls, xlsx , xlsm, xlsb
    Case 1: Extensions = "xls"    'Only  xls
    Case 2: Extensions = "xlsx"    'Only xlsx
    Case 3: Extensions = "xlsm"    'Only xlsm
    Case 4: Extensions = "xlsb"    'Only xlsb
    Case 5: Extensions = "csv"    'Only csv
    Case 6: Extensions = "txt"    'Only txt
    Case 7: Extensions = ".*"    'All files with extension, use *.* for everything
    Case 8: Extensions = "(xlsx|xlsm|xlsb)"  'xlsx, xlsm , xlsb
    Case 9: Extensions = "(csv|txt)"   'csv and txt files
        'You can add more filter options if you want,
    End Select

    Select Case FileFilterOption
    Case 0: FileNameFilter = "'.*/[^~][^/]*\\." & Extensions & "$' "  'No Filter
    Case 1: FileNameFilter = "'.*/" & FileNameFilterStr & "[^~][^/]*\\." & Extensions & "$' "    'Begins with
    Case 2: FileNameFilter = "'.*/[^~][^/]*" & FileNameFilterStr & "\\." & Extensions & "$' "    ' Ends With
    Case 3: FileNameFilter = "'.*/([^~][^/]*" & FileNameFilterStr & "[^/]*|" & FileNameFilterStr & "[^/]*)\\." & Extensions & "$' "   'Contains
    End Select

    folderPath = MacScript("tell text 1 thru -2 of " & Chr(34) & folderPath & _
                           Chr(34) & " to return quoted form of it's POSIX Path")
    folderPath = Replace(folderPath, "'\''", "'\\''")

    If Val(Application.Version) < 15 Then
        ScriptToRun = ScriptToRun & "set foundPaths to paragraphs of (do shell script """ & "find -E " & _
                      folderPath & " -iregex " & FileNameFilter & "-maxdepth " & _
                      Level & """)" & Chr(13)
        ScriptToRun = ScriptToRun & "repeat with thisPath in foundPaths" & Chr(13)
        ScriptToRun = ScriptToRun & "set thisPath's contents to (POSIX file thisPath) as text" & Chr(13)
        ScriptToRun = ScriptToRun & "end repeat" & Chr(13)
        ScriptToRun = ScriptToRun & "set astid to AppleScript's text item delimiters" & Chr(13)
        ScriptToRun = ScriptToRun & "set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return" & Chr(13)
        ScriptToRun = ScriptToRun & "set foundPaths to foundPaths as text" & Chr(13)
        ScriptToRun = ScriptToRun & "set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid" & Chr(13)
        ScriptToRun = ScriptToRun & "foundPaths"
    Else
        ScriptToRun = ScriptToRun & "do shell script """ & "find -E " & _
                      folderPath & " -iregex " & FileNameFilter & "-maxdepth " & _
                      Level & """ "
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    MyFiles = MacScript(ScriptToRun)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function RDB_Last(choice As Integer, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
'Case 1 = last row
'Case 2 = last column
'Case 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Integer

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                            after:=rng.Cells(1), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                            after:=rng.Cells(1), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       after:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        after:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            RDB_Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Select
End Function



----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Option Explicit

Sub MergeCode1()
    Dim BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim rnum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim MySplit As Variant
    Dim FileInMyFiles As Long
    Dim Mybook As Workbook
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim destrange As Range
    Dim SourceRcount As Long

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Font.Size = 36
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Value = "Please Wait"
    rnum = 1

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Clear MyFiles to be sure that it not return old info if no files are found
    MyFiles = ""

    'Get the files, set the level of folders and extension in the code line below
    Call GetFilesOnMacWithOrWithoutSubfolders(Level:=1, ExtChoice:=0, FileFilterOption:=0, FileNameFilterStr:="")
    'Level                       :  1= Only the files in the folder you select, 2 to ? levels of subfolders
    'ExtChoice               :  0=(xls|xlsx|xlsm|xlsb), 1=xls , 2=xlsx, 3=xlsm, 4=xlsb, 5=csv, 6=txt, 7=all files, 8=(xlsx|xlsm|xlsb), 9=(csv|txt)
    'FileFilterOption     :  0=No Filter, 1=Begins, 2=Ends, 3=Contains
    'FileNameFilterStr  : Search string used when FileFilterOption = 1, 2 or 3

    ' Work with the files if MyFiles is not empty.
    If MyFiles <> "" Then

        MySplit = Split(MyFiles, Chr(13))
        For FileInMyFiles = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)

            Set Mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Mybook = Workbooks.Open(MySplit(FileInMyFiles))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not Mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With Mybook.Worksheets(3)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("O10:AK1208")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        Mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MySplit(FileInMyFiles)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                Mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next FileInMyFiles
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Value = "Ready"
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub



You can use Conditional Compilation to manage running different code on Mac vs PC.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-conditional-compilation

I don't know anything about MacScript, but it looks like it's for getting a list of all matching files, in which case there are plenty of examples of that here on SO if you search.  Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883838/getting-a-list-of-filtered-filenames-from-directory-and-sub-directories-into-an/58884001#58884001

The script only runs on Macs. I'm trying to run it on a PC and it's not doing anything. What parts of the script should I update so that it can work on both a PC and a Mac? The conditional compilation did not work.

Did you look at the link in my second comment?

...seems like you only need to find *.xls* files in the top-level of a user-selected folder, so you only need to use Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) and a loop usiing Dir().  There are plenty of examples of that here on SO.

As noted above you can use Conditional Compilation.
In a module add this:
Public MyFiles As String

'use conditional compilation to ensure Mac/Win compatibility
#If Mac Then
    'place code for `GetFilesOnMacWithOrWithoutSubfolders` here
#End If

#If Win64 Then
    'PC equivalent of `GetFilesOnMacWithOrWithoutSubfolders` (as used
    '   in the posted use case) 
    Sub GetFilesOnPC(filePattern As String)
        Dim folder As String, f As String, res As String
        'ask the user to select a folder
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            .Title = "Select source folder"
            If .Show = True Then
                If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                    folder = .SelectedItems(1)
                End If
            End If
        End With
        If Len(folder) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no folder selected
        'check for file matches
        f = Dir(folder & "\" & filePattern, vbNormal)
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            res = res & IIf(Len(res) > 0, vbCr, "") & f
            f = Dir() 'next file
        Loop
        MyFiles = res
    End Sub
#End If

Then in your main code:
MyFiles = ""
#If Mac Then
    'Get the files, set the level of folders and extension in the code line below
    Call GetFilesOnMacWithOrWithoutSubfolders(Level:=1, ExtChoice:=0, FileFilterOption:=0, FileNameFilterStr:="")
    'Level                       :  1= Only the files in the folder you select, 2 to ? levels of subfolders
    'ExtChoice               :  0=(xls|xlsx|xlsm|xlsb), 1=xls , 2=xlsx, 3=xlsm, 4=xlsb, 5=csv, 6=txt, 7=all files, 8=(xlsx|xlsm|xlsb), 9=(csv|txt)
    'FileFilterOption     :  0=No Filter, 1=Begins, 2=Ends, 3=Contains
    'FileNameFilterStr  : Search string used when FileFilterOption = 1, 2 or 3
#End If

#If Win64 Then
    GetFilesOnPC "*.xls*"
#End If

