Get full path of a file inside a subfolder
I have a folder with many subfolders inside. In one of these subfolders, there is a file whose path I need to get. The problem is that I only know the main folder path and partial name of the file.
For example:
The full file path is "C:\Documents\Folder1\Subfolder1\the_Australian_wildlife.pdf"
From this path I only know the following data:
-The main folder path: "C:\Documents\Folder1"
-Partial name of file: "Australian"
I have tried with the following code, but it only works if there are not subfolders inside of the folder. Any idea how I could manage it through VBA?
Sub Get_file_path

Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim fPath as String
Dim filePartialName as String

filePartialName="Australian"
fPath="C:\Documents\Folder1"
filePath = fPath & "\" & "*" & filePartialName & "*"

'Check if file is in folder
If Len(Dir(filePath)) <> 0 Then 'file exists
    fileName = Dir(filePath) 'extension is included
    Get_file_path = fPath & "\" & fileName
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub


See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884001/478884

Thanks @Tim Williams. It is exactly what I was looking for.
